Power failure stopped replications
New to work with replication - unable to figure out solution as this runs on prod. Kindly help me with a fix. - Thank you!
Error messages:

The process could not execute 'sp_repldone/sp_replcounters' on
''. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20011)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20011
Warning: Fatal error 9004 occurred at Aug  2 2024  9:48AM. Note the
error and time, and contact your system administrator. (Source:
MSSQLServer, Error number: 21) Get help: http://help/21
The process could not set the last distributed transaction. (Source:
MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22017) Get help:
http://help/MSSQL_REPL22017
The process could not execute 'sp_repldone/sp_replcounters' on
''. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22037)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL22037


Have you tried reinitializing the snapshot?

Yes. Setting up replication, and operating replication are two different skillsets.  You need to learn how to monitor the replication topology, and how to reinitialize subscriptions, or recreate the replication topology as needed.

@J.D. Yes - got to know that we need to reinitialize snapshot. Still yet to perform. - thank you!

Thank you @David Browne - Yes, i did some research. Will spend time to learn.

Same or different error message after reinitializing?

No error message.

From here, https://repltalk.com/2010/02/19/the-process-could-not-execute-sp_repldonesp_replcounters/
Did execute the below statements stepwise
DBCC OPENTRAN(@DATABASE_NAME) - to check Old distributed & Non-distributed LSNs
EXEC sp_replrestart - To restart the application
DBCC OPENTRAN(@DATABASE_NAME) - to ensure the old non-distributed LSN greater than distributed LSN
Then Scheduled re-initialization at midnight.
That fixed the issue.
